# Find video file position using an image match

Tags: linux, video, images, ffmpeg, video-editing

What would be the best tool / method to automatically find a position from an video file, where the frame approximately matches* a given image?

Basically, a command to: *"Find the position where [image.jpg] appears in the [video.mpg]"*

Preferably with **ffmpeg**, or some other linux command-line tool.

<sup>* - or maybe the frame which best of all of the frames in the video, matches the image</sup>

Comment: If something like this exists, then it's really cool

Comment: I would think there are some image matching libraries somewhere - combining those with a tool that extracts frames from video shouldn't really be that hard. If such doesn't exist, I'm quite tempted to write one myself. :)

Comment: There are some [amazing image matching tools out there](http://www.visipics.info)! (Although this one is not for linux, it will compare different image formats, dimensions, color depths, and even partial images; so maybe there is a similar CLI tool or library for linux that you can pipe outputs?)

Comment: So, have you wrote such a tool yourself? Would've been really useful.

Comment: @user3075942 Not yet, but the concept is still on my todo. :)

Answer (score 4):

**2023 way to do this**

```
ffmpeg  -i "video.mp4" -r 1 -loop 1 -i image.png -an -filter_complex "blend=difference:shortest=1,blackframe=90:32" -f null -
```

Notice the 90 there, if set to 100 it would only match equally, with lower numbers you get to set a fuzzy search criteria

Answer (score 2):

[framepos.sh](https://github.com/milahu/random/blob/master/framepos.sh) is a bash script to search images in a video file,
using ffmpeg and [findimagedupes](https://gitlab.com/opennota/findimagedupes).

with the `threshold` variable, you can specify the fuzziness of the search.

we use the script with success to remove intros and outros from tv show episodes.

for "audiodetect" we use [dejavu](https://github.com/worldveil/dejavu), and maybe [pyAudioAnalysis Segmentation](https://github.com/tyiannak/pyAudioAnalysis/wiki/5.-Segmentation) can be used.

relevant pseudocode ....

most complexity in the code is to run "extract" and "compare" in parallel, to improve speed and efficiency:

```
function framepos() {

    # extract frames. run in background
    # bmp format is faster than png or jpg
    $ffmpeg_cmd \
        $ff_args -i "$V" \
        ${tmp_pre}frame-%04d.bmp \
        2>/dev/null &
    pid=$!

    # output function for findimagedupes
    script_include=$(cat <<-'EOF'
        VIEW () {
            for f in "$@"
            do
                echo -n "$f"
                echo -ne "\t\t\t\t"
            done
            echo
        }
EOF
    )

    n2=0
    while true
    do
        n=$(ls ${tmp_pre}frame-*.bmp 2>/dev/null | wc -l)

        (( $n == 0 )) && {
            kill -0 $pid 2>/dev/null || {
                # extract done
                echo debug found no match >&2
                break
            }

            kill -SIGCONT $pid
            sleep $step_duration
            continue
        }
        (( $n == 1 )) && {
            # only one frame extracted.
            # if ffmpeg is still extracting, this file is incomplete
            kill -0 $pid 2>/dev/null && {
                # extract running
                kill -SIGCONT $pid
                sleep $step_duration
                continue
            }
            n2=1
        }
        (( 1 < $n && $n <= $frames_bufsize )) && {
            # frame buffer not full
            # if extract is running, then wait before compare
            kill -0 $pid 2>/dev/null && {
                # extract running
                kill -SIGCONT $pid
                sleep $step_duration
                continue
            }
            n2=$(( $n - 1 ))
        }
        (( $n > $frames_bufsize )) && {         #echo found $n frames
            # pause frame extraction to save space
            # extract is faster than compare
            kill -SIGSTOP $pid
            n2=$(( $n - 1 ))
        }

        echo compare $n2 frames
        break_while=false
        for I_cur in "${I[@]}"
        do
            # we need the "real path" for findimagedupes
            pattern=$(readlink -f "$I_cur")

            # call findimagedupes
            # to find "visually similar images"
            res=$(
                ls ${tmp_pre}frame-*.bmp \
                | head -n $n2 \
                | xargs findimagedupes -t $threshold \
                    -i "$script_include" "$pattern" \
                | grep -a "$pattern"
            )

            if [ ! -z "$res" ]
            then
                res=$(
                    echo "$res" \
                    | sed 's/\t\t\t\t/\n/g' \
                    | grep -v '^$' \
                    | grep -v "$pattern" \
                    | sort \
                    | head -n 1 \
                    | sed -E 's/^.*frame-(.*?)\.bmp$/\1/'
                )

                # get frame time
                # note: frame numbers start with 1
                # frame minus one:
                t=$(
                    echo $T1 $res $fps \
                    | awk '{printf "%.4f\n", $1 + ( ( $2 - 2 ) / $3 ) }'
                )
                # matching frame:
                #   | awk '{printf "%.4f\n", $1 + ( ( $2 - 1 ) / $3 ) }'

                # return
                echo $t

                # stop extracting
                kill -9 $pid 2>/dev/null

                # remove all temp files
                rm ${tmp_pre}frame-*.bmp

                break_while=true
                break
            fi
        done

        $break_while && break

        # remove processed temp files
        (( $n2 > 0 )) \
        && ls ${tmp_pre}frame-*.bmp | head -n $n2 | xargs rm
    done
}
```

Comment: sed: 1: "s/^.* (.*?) fps.*$/\1/": RE error: repetition-operator operand invalid
fps =
date: illegal option -- d
usage: date [-jnRu] [-r seconds|file] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]]
            [-I[date | hours | minutes | seconds]]
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]
dur = 
near T1 = -12
near T2 = -8
awk: division by zero
 input record number 1, file 
 source line number 1
exact T1 =
awk: division by zero
 input record number 1, file 
 source line number 1
exact T2 =
extract frames to /tmp/mv-1672224887.frame-%04d.bmp

Comment: extract ... debug found no match
error frame not found framepos doesnt work anymore

Comment: all i did was run ./framepos.sh ghost_nimble_guardian_subtle_arrow_1.mp4 1.png

Comment: seems like the bash script is not portable to your system. if you really need this, please file a bug at https://github.com/milahu/random - or better, find a script in python, where this is easier to implement, see [Find Frames in a video that matches an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54236427/find-frames-in-a-video-that-matches-an-image) or [Template matching with video input](https://forum.opencv.org/t/template-matching-with-video-input/6563) or [Template Matching with OpenCV](https://debuggercafe.com/template-matching-with-opencv/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [md5](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#md5-1) and [framemd5](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#framemd5-1) muxers **if the image and frame are exactly the same**. Example:

1. Get MD5 sum of target image:

   ```
   $ ffmpeg -i frame.jpg -f md5 - 2>&1 | grep MD5
   MD5=b7fb5124a65108ebb067129d9d81ed57
   ```
2. Find exact image frame in video:

   ```
   $ ffmpeg -i video.mov -f framemd5 - 2>&1 | grep b7fb5124a65108ebb067129d9d81ed57
     0,        62,        62,         1,  1424400, b7fb5124a65108ebb067129d9d81ed57
   ```

The output numbers refer to: `stream_index, packet_dts, packet_pts, packet_duration, packet_size, MD5`.

However, this is probably not what you're looking for. Conceivably this will work if `video.mov` is mjpeg; such as if you make a [video from jpg inputs](http://ffmpeg.org/faq.html#How-do-I-encode-single-pictures-into-movies_003f) and [stream copy](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) them to the output:

```
ffmpeg -pattern_type glob -i "*.jpg" -codec copy output.mkv
```

Comment: You're right, exact match is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: @IlariKajaste Consider submitting a feature request to the [FFmpeg Bug Tracker](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/). Mention any libraries that may do what you want if you find any.

Comment: A feature like this might be a bit out of scope as direct feature of FFmpeg. But with a small script and some piping this might be possible. I don't know, though, which is why I'm asking. :)

Comment: @IlariKajaste There are already several "detect" filters in ffmpeg: `silencedetect`, `volumedetect`, `blackdetect`, `blackframe`, `cropdetect`, `edgedetect`, so a "`framedetect`" may not be out of scope.

Comment: Ah, yes, good point!