# FFmpeg - Cut video from the beginning until a certain pixel is colored at a specific color

Tags: ffmpeg, video, colors, video-editing

I am new to working with **FFmpeg** and would like to automate video trimming but can't find a way to do it.

So, what I would like to achieve is this: **I want to delete the beginning of a video file until a certain pixel (x,y) is colored gray (0x303030)**.

I am sure that somewhere in the video, say, pixel (100,50) will be colored gray (0x303030). And I want the video to begin exactly at this point.

Optionally it would be great if I could move a few micro/mili seconds back-and-forth from this exact point so can have some spare time.

Tried many complex commands but nothing works for me :(

For example I've tried:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf "select='gt(scene,0.01)+eq(pict_type\,I)*eq(r(X,Y)\,128)*eq(g(X,Y)\,128)*eq(b(X,Y)\,128)',setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB" output.mp4
```

The same thing I want to do from the end of the video...

Please help!

Comment: Please don't cross-post to multiple SE sites. Pick one & stick to it, or flag for migration. 
[Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/) - https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/36209/ffmpeg-cut-video-from-the-beginning-until-a-certain-pixel-is-colored-at-a-spec

Answer (score 0):

Does the in.mp4 have some audio that you could use instead to find where to cut?

You could also try to do something similar to this...
[Find video file position using an image match](https://superuser.com/questions/663731/find-video-file-position-using-an-image-match)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).